# Show the site's moderator chatroom on the flag dashboard

Tags: feature-request, chat, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

As a moderator, on the flag dashboard (`/admin/dashboard`), I see a box with links to chat rooms. The box always seems to contain the same two rooms: the Teachers' Lounge and a room called MOBotics. I guess these rooms are selected by some measure of recent activity. I just discovered MOBotics and I see how it could be useful to advertise it (I wasn't aware of it; I should consider myself fortunate that its subject matter hasn't reached the sites that I moderate), but that's not a useful link in the sense that I don't have a reason to visit MOBotics. And there's also a link to the Teachers' Lounge in another box titled “Unsure?” (and besides I know the URL by heart).

What I'd like to have on this page is a link to *this* site's moderator room, if any. I don't know how you could identify which room is the mod room: most sites' mod rooms are low-activity (which is why I never remember their URLs). But it would be nice to find a way, because that's the one page that I often want to reach from the flag dashboard and I have no better way than the generic “chat” link, usually clicking “show frozen/deleted rooms” and typing something like “moderator” in the search box.

Please identify the site's mod chat room (if there is one) and link to it on the flag dashboard.

Comment: Simply having a way to search only the mod-private rooms for the site would help, similar to the way you can filter out the frozen or deleted ones. Mod rooms are often frozen but active, of course.

Comment: This would also be phenomenally useful for CMs, rather than often having to dig through the list of frozen chat rooms to find what the private chat room for the mods (if one even exists) might be named.